# Android: How to change the text size of the application name

Tags: android

Is it possible to change an application's name text size in order to fit on one line. On my device the application name is written on two lines like this:

```
Applicatio
n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't influence the way `Launcher` shows these labels on the screen other way than from Launcher's settings (if there's any in one you use).

BTW: it is not application name to be precise.